# How to properly delete everything from QContainer<Object*>

Tags: c++, qt

Theses are 3 version that we use in our code. We would like to standardise. It looks like the 2nd and 3rd are the fastest? But should we call .clear() in the 2nd/3rd version?

1st

```
qDeleteAll(container);
container.clear();
```

2nd

```
while (!container.isEmpty())
   container.removeLast();
```

3rd

```
while (!container.isEmpty())
   delete container.takeLast();
```

Comment: *"It looks like the 2nd and 3rd are the fastest?"* Don't guess about performance. *"But should we call .clear() in the 2nd/3rd version?"* That obviously depends on what `removeLast()` and `takeLast()` do.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that `removeLast` deletes the object.

Comment: @Hayt removeLast calls : `Q_INLINE_TEMPLATE void QList<T>::node_destruct(Node *n)
{
    if (QTypeInfo<T>::isLarge || QTypeInfo<T>::isStatic) delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(n->v);
    else if (QTypeInfo<T>::isComplex) reinterpret_cast<T*>(n)->~T();
}`

Comment: Well I just checked the documentation and there is noting mentioned that it deletes. Also if you have `QObject*` in your container. So it will delete a `QObject**` (note the `T*` cast) so it will delete a pointer to the pointer but not the object.

Comment: You're looking at implementation details. The `node_destruct` sure deletes something - but it's not your object, it's the **node**, an implementation detail of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using an *owning* `QList<QObject*>`, you should derive from it and make a custom container that manages the object lifetime the way you expect it to. **Manual resource management is a bug waiting to happen. Avoid it.**

Regarding your alternatives:

```
qDeleteAll(container);
container.clear();
```

Works fine. You'd expect it to be fastest, since the container is never resized.

```
while (!container.isEmpty())
   container.removeLast();
```

Leaks storage for all elements.

```
while (!container.isEmpty())
   delete container.takeLast();
```

Works fine. You'd expect it to be slower than the first alternative, since you continuously shrink the container. This will have some overhead no matter what.

As an alternative, in modern code you probably could use a `std::list` and store the objects by value:

```
std::list<MyObject> objects;
objects.emplace_back(...);
...
```

You can also use a `QObject` as an object container, it's guaranteed to dispose of its children when you destroy it, after all.

Comment: @deW1 If you don't have a compiler supporting C++11, then you can't use `emplace_back`.

Comment: Ah okay that's what you meant